# Pandas: drop_duplicates with condition

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Is there any way to use `drop_duplicates` together with conditions? For example, let's take the following Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Customer_Name': ['Carl', 'Carl', 'Mark', 'Joe', 'Joe'],
'Customer_Id': [1000,None,None,None,50000]
})
```

Based on this Dataframe I would like to derive a Dataframe with distinct rows for `Customer_Id` and `Customer_Name`

```
    Customer_Id Customer_Name
0    1000        Carl
2    NaN         Mark
5    50000       Joe
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use the `drop_duplicates` method for this as this method would always delete the first or last duplicated occurrences.

However, in my case this differs (see Carl and Joe). Moreover, I cannot just delete all rows with None entries in the Customer_Id column as this would also delete the entry for Mark.

I deeply appreciate any help.

Comment: may be you can use something like `df.groupby('Customer_Name').first()`?

Comment: What should happen if you have 2 not null rows for one customer?

Comment: Hi Roman, then you can take the first. You can assume the names are the same

Answer (score 1):

this one is working on your example:

```
>>> df.groupby('Customer_Name').first().reset_index()
  Customer_Name  Customer_Id
0          Carl         1000
1           Joe        50000
2          Mark          NaN
```

But I have to check how `first()` treating missing values to be sure it's working consistently.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you only the highest numbered `Customer_Id` or `NaN` if unavailable

```
df.groupby('Customer_Name').Customer_Id.max().reset_index()

  Customer_Name  Customer_Id
0          Carl         1000
1           Joe        50000
2          Mark          NaN
```